# JAVA Liberty App won't start in Bluemix

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a Java web app. When it is deployed to Bluemix, it fails to start. I see the following logs:

```
 2016-06-23T14:06:37.13-0400 [API/5]      OUT Created app with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:06:38.08-0400 [API/3]      OUT Updated app with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d ({"route"=>"dba589f3-ece3-4ffc-bef8-bd1147a8feb4"})
    2016-06-23T14:07:03.94-0400 [DEA/91]     OUT Got staging request for app with id 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:07:21.04-0400 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
    2016-06-23T14:07:22.92-0400 [STG/0]      OUT     -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v3.0-20160608-1450
    2016-06-23T14:07:22.92-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving IBM 1.8.0_20160428 JRE (ibm-java-jre-8.0-3.0-pxa6480sr3-20160428_01-cloud.tgz) ... (0.0s)
    2016-06-23T14:07:24.61-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          Expanding JRE to .java ...
     (1.6s)
    2016-06-23T14:07:24.63-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving App Management 1.17.0_20160418-1204 (app-mgmt_v1.17-20160418-1204.zip) ... (0.0s)
    2016-06-23T14:07:24.81-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          Expanding App Management to .app-management (0.1s)
    2016-06-23T14:07:26.02-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          Installing archive ... (1.2s)
    2016-06-23T14:07:26.10-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Warning: Liberty feature set is not specified. Using the default feature set: ["beanValidation-1.1", "cdi-1.2", "ejbLite-3.2", "el-3.0", "jaxrs-2.0", "jdbc-4.1", "jndi-1.0", "jpa-2.1", "jsf-2.2", "jsonp-1.0", "jsp-2.3", "managedBeans-1.0", "servlet-3.1", "websocket-1.1"]. For the best results, explicitly set the features via the JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY environment variable or deploy the application as a server directory or packaged server with a custom server.xml file.
    2016-06-23T14:07:26.12-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet
    2016-06-23T14:07:26.76-0400 [STG/0]      ERR
    2016-06-23T14:07:42.53-0400 [STG/91]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (139M)
    2016-06-23T14:08:15.93-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"24102163143543c6ad50bf7b955850ba", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705295}
    2016-06-23T14:08:15.94-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"24102163143543c6ad50bf7b955850ba", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705295}
    2016-06-23T14:10:00.94-0400 [DEA/164]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:10:17.17-0400 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"7845d7174d00479a8592e46888c52a68", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705417}
2016-06-23T14:10:17.20-0400 [API/4]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"7845d7174d00479a8592e46888c52a68", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705417}
    2016-06-23T14:11:19.75-0400 [DEA/19]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:11:45.25-0400 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"94ef9de856ee417dbdb5c433a37c5c19", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705505}
    2016-06-23T14:11:45.25-0400 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"94ef9de856ee417dbdb5c433a37c5c19", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705505}
    2016-06-23T14:12:19.58-0400 [DEA/55]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:12:38.78-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"77f1946dadd94d7f8ada2fff22abd4c7", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705558}
    2016-06-23T14:12:39.01-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"77f1946dadd94d7f8ada2fff22abd4c7", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705558}
    2016-06-23T14:14:20.27-0400 [DEA/159]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:14:43.03-0400 [API/9]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"fd16fc1e31a949c7811ce1bc4a518cc3", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705683}
    2016-06-23T14:14:43.10-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"fd16fc1e31a949c7811ce1bc4a518cc3", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705683}
    2016-06-23T14:17:05.64-0400 [DEA/42]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:17:41.29-0400 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"affd34e4d6be4ca6b8e721c110d7b21a", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1466705861}
    2016-06-23T14:17:52.51-0400 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d ({"name"=>"test-push-prem89-1358", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "memory"=>512, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "health_check_timeout"=>180})
    2016-06-23T14:18:58.22-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
    2016-06-23T14:19:16.04-0400 [DEA/18]     OUT Got staging request for app with id5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:19:29.83-0400 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
    2016-06-23T14:19:30.40-0400 [STG/18]     OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)
    2016-06-23T14:19:31.70-0400 [STG/0]      OUT     -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v3.0-20160608-1450
    2016-06-23T14:19:31.70-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving IBM 1.8.0_20160428 JRE (ibm-java-jre-8.0-3.0-pxa6480sr3-20160428_01-cloud.tgz) ... (0.0s)
    2016-06-23T14:19:32.84-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          Expanding JRE to .java ...(1.1s)
    2016-06-23T14:19:32.84-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving App Management 1.17.0_20160418-1204 (app-mgmt_v1.17-20160418-1204.zip) ... (0.0s)
    2016-06-23T14:19:32.99-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          Expanding App Management to .app-management (0.1s)
    2016-06-23T14:19:32.99-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty-16.0.0.2-201606081450.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
    2016-06-23T14:19:34.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT          Installing archive ... (1.1s)
    2016-06-23T14:19:34.18-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Warning: Liberty feature set is not specified. Using the default feature set: ["beanValidation-1.1", "cdi-1.2", "ejbLite-3.2", "el-3.0", "jaxrs-2.0", "jdbc-4.1", "jndi-1.0", "jpa-2.1", "jsf-2.2", "jsonp-1.0", "jsp-2.3", "managedBeans-1.0", "servlet-3.1", "websocket-1.1"]. For the best results, explicitly set the features via the JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY environment variable or deploy the application as a server directory or packaged server with a custom server.xml file.
    2016-06-23T14:19:34.20-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet
    2016-06-23T14:19:34.93-0400 [STG/0]      ERR
    2016-06-23T14:19:48.07-0400 [STG/18]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (139M)
    2016-06-23T14:19:57.29-0400 [DEA/18]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:20:13.76-0400 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"d5ca2275f8344a8c8df469e7e3b04976", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706013}
    2016-06-23T14:20:13.78-0400 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"d5ca2275f8344a8c8df469e7e3b04976", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706013}
    2016-06-23T14:20:49.38-0400 [DEA/112]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:21:06.51-0400 [API/6]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"ca5f656ce2754baea29f7bca57a2415c", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706066}
    2016-06-23T14:21:06.56-0400 [API/9]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"ca5f656ce2754baea29f7bca57a2415c", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706066}
    2016-06-23T14:21:52.80-0400 [DEA/26]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:22:32.02-0400 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"30b8659bfcf246718f5dbcf5151da605", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706151}
    2016-06-23T14:22:32.08-0400 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"30b8659bfcf246718f5dbcf5151da605", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706151}
    2016-06-23T14:22:41.36-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"e210399e-b688-4284-a50c-b1a57331751a", "instance"=>"affd34e4d6be4ca6b8e721c110d7b21a", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706161}
    2016-06-23T14:23:05.65-0400 [DEA/2]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:23:20.99-0400 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"7a21fab6dd6a4e7b8a40455ef7225ca5", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706201}
    2016-06-23T14:23:21.05-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"7a21fab6dd6a4e7b8a40455ef7225ca5", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706201}
    2016-06-23T14:25:05.27-0400 [DEA/54]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:27:34.88-0400 [DEA/53]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:28:06.02-0400 [API/6]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"2fb16b5a9d6a4375a6b9bc76bdf1d625", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706485}
    2016-06-23T14:30:30.76-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"b89e3e8a045443efb0522335ac851c2a", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706630}
    2016-06-23T14:33:06.03-0400 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"2fb16b5a9d6a4375a6b9bc76bdf1d625", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466706785}
    2016-06-23T14:36:12.70-0400 [DEA/50]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:36:45.23-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"74f2550073a445c8bf2f60b6d0187345", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1466707005}
    2016-06-23T14:41:45.33-0400 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"74f2550073a445c8bf2f60b6d0187345", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466707305}
    2016-06-23T14:43:49.68-0400 [DEA/90]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T14:44:09.00-0400 [API/5]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"dece52cc66f044b583ccd69ec169c9ff", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1466707448}
    2016-06-23T14:49:08.99-0400 [API/6]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"dece52cc66f044b583ccd69ec169c9ff", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466707749}
    2016-06-23T15:01:45.48-0400 [DEA/147]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d
    2016-06-23T15:02:14.79-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"4fb05450de33494da8f42d3ca767d956", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466708534}
    2016-06-23T15:02:14.81-0400 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid 5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"5966c029-0a4b-4433-9861-c2999922314d", "version"=>"9da04bfd-0f8a-4118-ba5f-c0481190cee0", "instance"=>"4fb05450de33494da8f42d3ca767d956", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1466708534}
```

What should be added to make it deploy right?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with manifest.yml .. I had a command in manifest.yml that did the UI build `command: npm build` which was essentially overriding what the command that buildpack would use to start the app using Liberty runtime with "npm build" command. So removing the `command` argument from `manifest.yml` took care of it!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be the issue:

```
2016-06-23T14:19:34.18-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Warning: Liberty feature set is not specified. Using the default feature set: ["beanValidation-1.1", "cdi-1.2", "ejbLite-3.2", "el-3.0", "jaxrs-2.0", "jdbc-4.1", "jndi-1.0", "jpa-2.1", "jsf-2.2", "jsonp-1.0", "jsp-2.3", "managedBeans-1.0", "servlet-3.1", "websocket-1.1"]. For the best results, explicitly set the features via the JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY environment variable or deploy the application as a server directory or packaged server with a custom server.xml file.
2016-06-23T14:19:34.20-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet
2016-06-23T14:19:34.93-0400 [STG/0]      ERR
```

Does your app need a different feature set then the default provided by liberty?  Have you tried running the app locally on a Liberty server to see if it runs with that feature set?

Comment: Yes it does run locally or for that matter by deloting the war to a newly created liberty app with same feature set as listedabove